# NavigationView and Translucent Status Bar

Tags: android, themes, navigation-drawer, material-design, statusbar

I followed all the tips on SO on how to achieve this and no success so far... I would like to have a Semi-transparent/transparent (not sure of the difference) status bar.

**UPDATE 25/03/16:** I tried all kinds of Theme attributes without progress. Updated question with what I attempted for the v21 styles file and a **Bounty**.

**Does anyone have an idea?**

`fitSystemWindows` is set in both my `DrawerLayout` and `NavigationView` in the xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
                     ...
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/tealfifty"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_view_items" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my app theme:

```
   <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/teal</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/tealDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/purple700</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">@color/teal</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/iron</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/iron</item>
</style>
```

and my `v21\styles`

```
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementsUseOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

I also tried including those in the v21 styles:

```
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
```

Current result:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What do you have now? (Screenshot)

Comment: I added a screenshot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at this:

[image]

So the files are:

**values:**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

**values-v21**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**and `MainActivity` layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello World!" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and the result:

**nav_header:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Hello Again"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="me@android.com"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have most of this in my files, whatever was different I edited and still no change. I believe I have setup everything correctly but I once saw somewhere there's code that puts color over the toolbar even if its set to be transparent. So rather than checking if I did everything right in the layouts, maybe someone can suggest what I did after that to ruin it by adding colour...I don't know it's getting hopeless

Comment: For some reason windowActionBar and windowNoTitle properties weren't working when they were part of the main theme. I put them in a separate style .NoActionBar and changed the Manifest so that the Activities use it and then it worked! I've already checked this template but I guess I didn't bother to try everything cause it didn't seem logical. Thanks!