# How to get transparent action bar when a drawer is opened

Tags: java, android, android-drawer

How can I get a transparent action bar, like this in Google Play Store, when the drawer is opened in my app?

[image]

Comment: Hope this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510615/navigationview-and-translucent-status-bar